# OUnit Test Issues with Dune

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-dune, ounit

I have a project with this structure:

```
- dune
- main.ml
-- src/
---- dune
---- parser.ml
-- test/
---- dune
---- test_parser.ml
```

In `src/dune`, I have the following:

```
(library (name Parser))
```

In `test/dune`:

```
(test (name test_token_type) (libraries oUnit Parser))
```

When I go to run `dune build`, I get the complaint:

```
File "test/dune", line 1, characters 46-52:
1 | (test (name test_parser) (libraries oUnit Parser))
                                              ^^^^^^
```

Any ideas on how to resolve?

Comment: I think you left out the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue. It turns out that I had a `dune-project` file in the top-level path and inside the `test/parser` path. Most likely dune thought another project was introduced and didn't look for dependencies in parent paths or something similar.